# Converting from UTM to WGS84 using GeoTools?

Tags: coordinate-system, geotools, wgs84

I have created a function that reads a shapefile file and I get its geographic coordinates well. This works fine. My problem is that I need those coordinates in wgs84 format (latitude, longitude), but I cannot get it to work.

I used a 'Query' object, but its setCoordinateSystem method does not do anything.

This is my code:

```
public Geometry getGeometryDistrict(String refCatDistrict, String shapeFileDistrict){

                Geometry union = null;

                File shapeFile = new File (shapeFileDistrict);

                try {

                   Query query = new Query();
                   query.setCoordinateSystem(DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84);

                   Filter filter = CQL.toFilter("obj_co_id = '"+refCatDistrict+"'");
                   query.setFilter(filter);

                   FileDataStore storeDistrict = FileDataStoreFinder.getDataStore(shapeFile);

                   SimpleFeatureSource featureSource = storeDistrict.getFeatureSource();

                   SimpleFeatureCollection collection = featureSource.getFeatures(query);
                   SimpleFeature fDistrict = null;

                   ArrayList<Geometry> geometries = new ArrayList<>();

                   SimpleFeatureIterator itrDistrict = collection.features();

                   while(itrDistrict.hasNext()){

                      fDistrict = itrDistrict.next();

                      Geometry geomDistrict = (Geometry)fDistrict.getDefaultGeometry();
                      geometries.add(geomDistrict);

                   }

                   GeometryFactory factory = new GeometryFactory();

                   GeometryCollection geometryCollection = (GeometryCollection) factory.buildGeometry( geometries );

                   union = geometryCollection.union();

                   itrDistrict.close();
                   storeDistrict.dispose();

               }catch(IOException | NoSuchElementException | CQLException e){
                   Throwable cause = e.getCause();
                   System.out.println(cause);
               }

                return union;
            }
```

What should I change?

Comment: @RichardMorgan that is a good answer but not actually needed here.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`Query.setCoordinateSystemReproject(CRS)`](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/geotools/data/Query.html#setCoordinateSystemReproject-org.opengis.referencing.crs.CoordinateReferenceSystem-) not [`Query.setCoordinateSystem(CRS)`](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/geotools/data/Query.html#setCoordinateSystem-org.opengis.referencing.crs.CoordinateReferenceSystem-). One changes the output coordinates and the other tells the system what CRS the coordinates of any geometries in the query are in.

This code fetches the boundary of Pennsylvania in [EPSG:2272](https://epsg.io/2272).

```
public static void main(String[] args)
      throws IOException, CQLException, NoSuchAuthorityCodeException, FactoryException {
    File states = new File("/home/ian/Data/states/states.shp");
    FileDataStore ds = FileDataStoreFinder.getDataStore(states);
    Query query = new Query();
    query.setCoordinateSystemReproject(CRS.decode("EPSG:2272"));

    Filter filter = CQL.toFilter("STATE_ABBR = 'PA'");
    query.setFilter(filter);
    SimpleFeatureCollection collection = ds.getFeatureSource().getFeatures(query);
    try (SimpleFeatureIterator itr = collection.features()) {
      while (itr.hasNext()) {
        SimpleFeature feature = itr.next();
        System.out.println(feature.getDefaultGeometry());

      }
    }
  }
```

giving

```
MULTIPOLYGON (((2045557.7266281387 140806.06587454624, 1871110.379503949 143004.87968818948, 1803993.1961730379...
```

despite the input file being in WGS84 degrees.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I also tried with the setCoordinateSystemReproject method, but it shows me this runtime error:" java.io.IOException: Can not reproject data, the source CRS is not available".

Comment: then you need to fix your shapefile (make sure there is a `.prj` file), if you know the projection you can download the contents at http://epsg.io

Comment: I think that is precisely my problem. In the file structure there is no .prj file (in other projects i worked it does exist), but not in this one. My file structure had only three files extensions: .dbf, .shp, .shx... but no .prj

Comment: In case of not having a .prj file it could be generated in some way, or how could it be converted geometries from utm to wgs84 without that .prj file?

Comment: as I said you can generate a `.prj` file by going to http://epsg.io and looking for the UTM zone your data is in and downloading the OGC WKT file - for example if you need UTM 30N you would get http://epsg.io/32630.wkt and save it as "filename".prj

Comment: Thank you, that is a temporary solution. But not effective for an application, where every day users will be uploading dozens of different files. I need to do that same process (convert from utm to lat / lon) programmatically.

Comment: But you need to know what the projection of the input data is - is it always the same?

Comment: No, it's dinamic. Sometime will be cadastral information from Spain, sometime from France cadastral... Italy...

Comment: Most of them have 4 files (.dbf, .shp, .shx and .prj), but some do not have them all, only 3 (.dbf, .shp and .shx) ... without .prj . and my intention is to convert all the utm coordinates to lat/long automatically. If they have .prj I can easily do it with geoTools, but if they do not have that file, I do not see how to do it automatically.